# Access 2016 Query for Latitude Longitude

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two Database with Latitude and Longitude. I need to compare and find out the nearest point from the master database (Database A) comparing the second database (Database B)

Like I have 6000 (all unique) data in master I need to run the second database (150 data) and find out closest 150 coordinates from the Master Database

Answer (score -1):

```
You can use this query to find the distance between two points. For each point from DB1 find distance between points in DB2 and select min distance point.

This Query will give distance in KM,

Please note that this query you need to rewrite to make compatible with MSAccess DB.

ROUND(
    (
      (
        (
          ACOS(
            SIN((from.latitude * PI() / 180)) * SIN((to.latitude * PI() / 180))
 + COS((from.latitude * PI() / 180)) * COS((to.latitude * PI() / 180)) 
 * COS(((from.longitude- to.longitude) * PI() / 180))
          )
        ) * 180 / PI()
      ) * 60 * 1.1515
    ) * 1.609344,
    2
  ) AS distance
```